# Mapping SubCategories to list Categories using valueInjecter mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, valueinjecter

I want to map sub categories model which has foreign key for category model to categories model  using "valueinjecter" mapping.
I have made "viewmodel" and write `list<category>` type property in it and now I want to bind sub categories to it.

Tables are as follows according to your specifications
Categories table:

```
        Id Name
        1 gender
        2 Role
```

Sub Categories table:

```
         Id CategoryId Name
         1  1          Male
         2  1          Femal
         3  2          admin
         4  2          user
```

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this:

```
Mapper.AddMap<Customer, CustomerInput>(src =>
{
    var res = new CustomerInput();
    res.InjectFrom(src); // maps simple properties with same name and type
    res.Coll = src.Collection.Select(srcItem => Mapper.Map<CollItemResType>(srcItem)
    return res;
});
```